# I want to hide text box when click out side

Tags: jquery, html

In my new project I would like to add a search box with expanding width when click on icon.
I have created with that query width toggle but I need to hide the textbox when click outside too.

HTML:

```
<div class="search_box">
     <form>
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
     </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.search_box .fa-search').click(function(){
        jQuery('.search_box input').animate({width:'toggle'},500);

    });
});
```

Comment: You can use the `blur` event for tracking clicks outside the text box

Comment: Is your toggle even doing anything? You're passing it as a string...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.search_box input').blur(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Could also do this with just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if( !$(".search_box").is(e.target) ){ 
    //if your box isn't the target of click, hide it
        $(".search_box").hide();
    }
});
```

To use with your textbox, just change $(".search_box") for your textbox. Hope it helps